# 'kendo-angular-pdf-export' is not a known element

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular5

Template parse errors:

```
'kendo-angular-pdf-export' is not a known element:

1. If 'kendo-angular-pdf-export' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

2. If 'kendo-angular-pdf-export' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message
```

I have registered the module and imported it in my main file as described in https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/ but still keeps getting this error. I am working with Angular 5.

[Module is registered like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvRuL.png)

[My HTML file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvF0I.png)

[Screen shot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4wti.png)

**I found what I did wrong :**
[This is from telerik site of kendo-ui-angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r5zz.png)
But really it's kendo-pdf-export as shown in the example.

Comment: Could you show us what you have done

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I have edited the question. Please refer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you're using `kendo-angular-pdf-export`, base on the telerik kendo documentation it should be `kendo-pdf-export`

Comment: It worked. But I don't know why they mention kendo-angular-pdf-export in https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/. Thank you.

Comment: @UthpalaPathirana Looks like a typo to me. `kendo-angular-pdf-export` is actually the package-name (without the `@progress` scope)

Answer (score 0):

if you used the module. you must import "PDFModule" in your module .

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with

> kendo-dropdowlist

i.e. 'kendo-dropdownlist' is not a known element:

1. If 'kendo-dropdownlist' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-dropdownlist' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

I fixed this issue by importing relevant module in parent module.

In my case

> DropDownsModule

was needed to be import in module's import array.
Thanks.