# Adding kendo-angular-pdf-export gives 'kendo-angular-pdf-export' is not a known element error message

Tags: pdf, angular14, kendo-angular-ui

I know this seems like a duplicate question to this one
['kendo-angular-pdf-export' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146947/kendo-angular-pdf-export-is-not-a-known-element)

But I have an angular 14 app where I want to simply add the PDFExportModule into an existing application.

I am currently getting this error:

```
Error: src/app/pages/reports/meeting-report.component.html:20:1 - error NG8001: 'kendo-pdf-export' is not a known element:
1. If 'kendo-pdf-export' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-pdf-export' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

As a POC, I created a brand new application and followed instructions from here:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdf-export/get-started/

New Project
Ran this code

```
ng add @progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export
```

Package was added to package.json

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^12.0.0",
```

I added the PDFExportModule to the app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PDFExportModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PDFExportModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I added this snippet to the app.component.html

```
<kendo-pdf-export #pdf paperSize="A4" margin="2cm">
  content to be exported
</kendo-pdf-export>

<div class="example-config">
  <button kendoButton (click)="pdf.saveAs('my_document.pdf')">
    Save As PDF...
  </button>
</div>
```

In the new app, HTML renders and the PDF export works!!

[image: PDF export works!!]

Why might my existing app not be picking up on the export module?  And suggestions would be greatly appreciated!